# Android studio does not generate .md5 file at pocketsphinx demo project

Tags: android, android-studio, pocketsphinx

When I build [pocketsphinx demo](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) project by eclipse, IDE generates md5 files of some assest files. Hovewer If I do the same thing on Android Studio, It does not generate md5 files. In this case, the aplication that I compile with Android Studio gives an error shown below.

```
Failed to init recognizer java.io.FileNotFoundException: sync/models/grammar/digits.gram.md5
```

I am currently using Studio 1.0.2 version. 
SDK tools         :24.0.2
SDK platform-tools:21
SDK Build-tools   :21.1.2

What would be the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by making my own .gram.md5 file manually every time I changed my .gram file. I used this website to automatically generate the full text of the needed .gram.md5 file from the full text of my .gram file.

http://passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator/